# How do I use expect to test for less than

Tags: ruby, rspec

Relish suggests the following...

```
expect(actual).to be <  expected
```

However if I try...

```
 x.rand(10)
 expect(x).to be < 11
```

full spec

```
Then(/^I find each world produces just up to (\d+) fighters per turn and no higher$/) do |arg1|
    test = Planet.new
    test.production.each_index do |ndx|
       expect(test.production[ndx]).to be < 11
    end
  end
```

I'll get

```
undefined method `<' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::BePredicate:0x0000000268a3b0> (NoMethodError)
```

What is the current proper syntax to use expect in a less than comparison?

Comment: Your code looks consistent with http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/frames#Comparisons . What version of rspec-expectations are you using?

Comment: That is the correct syntax. Could you post your whole spec? And what version of RSpec are you using?

Comment: ```rspec-expectations (~> 3.5.0)```

Comment: Are you using another library to get the 'Then' syntax? Maybe that is causing problems.

Comment: @Joshua: that's cucumber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax looks good. I would first make a very small simple spec, independent of your code to see if your setup works. For example (it should fail btw ;):

```
describe 'test' do
  it 'works' do
    expect(2).to be < 1
  end
end
```

Comment: full list: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/frames#comparisons

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code for rspec-expectations it should return

RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Be not RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::BePredicate

Is it possible you have be_ ? That returns a RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::BePredicate in the following dummy test

```
describe 'test' do
  it 'works' do
    puts "be is a #{be.class}"
    puts "be_ is a #{be_.class}"

    puts "be is defined on #{method(:be)}"
    expect(2).to be_ < 1
  end
end
```

outputs

```
be is a RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Be 
be_ is a RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::BePredicate 
be is defined on #<Method:RSpec::ExampleGroups::Test(RSpec::Matchers)#be>
```

Alternatively maybe the be method has been redefined?